# How can I reach one of results from database in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to get some infos fro database in Python. Im new in it and I, unfortunatelly, wasted a lot of time for that. I expect that my problem is really simple. 
I have sth like that to fetch data:

```
    def FetchResults(con, sql):
       cur = con.cursor() 
       cur.execute(sql)
       return cur.fetchall()

_con = ConnectDB(config.host, config.user, config.passwd, config.db)
bbb = FetchResults(_con,"SELECT sth FROM sth")

for row in bbb:
   if row[0] != None:
      print row[0]
```

and my results are sth like that:

```
{"sth1":"aaaa","sth2":"qwe"}
{"sth1":"bbbb","sth2":"qwe"}
```

How can I reach for example "sth2" now

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load it via `json` module into a dictionary:

```
for row in bbb:
   if row[0]:
      data = json.loads(row[0])
      print data['sth2']
```